# Ajax promise not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I'm trying to use promise to return a comparison of current logged in user and a field from a list in SharePoint.

```
function compareCurrentUserWithListObject() {
   var userProp = this._userProfileProperties;
   var userName = userProp.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName'];

   return this._list.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    var promise = jQuery.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + element.user.get_lookupId() + ")",
       type: "GET",
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
     });
     promise.done(function(data) {
        return (data.d.Email.indexOf(userName) > -1);
     });
   });
}   

function init() {
   var userArray = this.compareCurrentUserWithListObject();
   userArray.done(function(res) {
     if (res.length > 0) {
       //Do some stuff after compare...
     }
   });
}
```

I'm not sure I'm using the .done correct here. Can someone help me?

EDIT:

Working code:

```
function compareCurrentUserWithListObject() {
   var userProp = this._userProfileProperties;
   var userName = userProp.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName'];

   return this._list.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    var promise = jQuery.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + element.user.get_lookupId() + ")",
       type: "GET",
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
     });
     promise.done(function(data) {
        return (data.d.Email.indexOf(userName) > -1);
     });
    return promise;
   });
}   

function init() {
   var userArray = this.compareCurrentUserWithListObject();
     if (userArray.length > 0) {
       //Do some stuff after compare...
     }
}
```

Comment: It should return a number, it finds a match in data.d.Email.indexOf(userName) but nothing happens in userArray.done.

Comment: Are you sure your working code is actually working? Because it seems that `userArray.length` is `> 0` **always**.

Comment: Checked debug and if it can't find a match userArray.length is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return the promise

```
function compareCurrentUserWithListObject() {
   var userProp = this._userProfileProperties;
   var userName = userProp.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName'];

   return this._list.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    var promise = jQuery.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + element.user.get_lookupId() + ")",
       type: "GET",
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
     });
     promise.done(function(data) {
        return (data.d.Email.indexOf(userName) > -1);
     });
     // return promise here
     return promise;
   });
}
```

or this (which is cleaner IMO):

```
function compareCurrentUserWithListObject() {
   var userProp = this._userProfileProperties;
   var userName = userProp.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName'];


    return jQuery.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + element.user.get_lookupId() + ")",
       type: "GET",
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });

}   


function init() {
   this.compareCurrentUserWithListObject()
   .done(function(data) {
     var res = data.d.Email.indexOf(userName) > -1;
     if (res.length > 0) {
       //Do some stuff after compare...
     }
   });

}
```

it looks like you want to modify the response before using it in `init`. There is a way to do that but I'd do it inside the `.done` callback when using it.

I didn't test this code so there might be mistakes. But the general answer is: you need to return the promise.

Comment: He can simply add a `return promise;` line. You don't need to modify the original code!

Comment: I know, but it looked like he wants to modify `data` before it's passed to the second `.done` callback.

Comment: Hmm. The first suggestion doesn't work. It never returns a value from the .done inside compareCurrentUserWithListObject function.

Comment: no it can't. It returns the response from the AJAX call. See my second suggestion. You need to move the number modifier into the `.done` callback inside `init`

Comment: Should I move out the this._list.filter outside the compare function also? You removed it from the second suggestion, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I got it to work with your first suggestion. Removed compareCurrentUserWithListObject.done from init and just used compareCurrentUserWithListObject.length and got the length from that.

Comment: ah I understand, I wasn't 100% sure why you've done it that way. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this using promises is to use `Promise.all()`. (I'll use Q promises as an example, but Promise.all is built into the JS6 promise API and several other promise libraries):

```
function getUserInfo(listItem) {
    var promise = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
             "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + listItem.user.get_lookupId() + ")",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
    return Q.Promise.when(promise);
}

function filterUsers(users) {
    var userProp = this._userProfileProperties;
    var userName = userProp.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName'];

    return users.filter(function (user) {
        return user.d.Email.indexOf(userName) > -1;
    });
}

function init() {
    Q.Promise.all(this._list.map(getUserInfo))
    .then(filterUsers.bind(this))
    .then(function (matchedUsers) {
       // matchedUsers is an array of all the users you want.
        // use it as needed
    });
}
```